# How to add the view name as body class

Tags: views, 8

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view(&$variables){
        $view = $variables['view'];
      if($view->name == "YOUR_VIEW_NAME" && $view->current_display == "MACHINE_NAME_OF_VIEW"){
        $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'page-'.$view->name;
    }
```

For some reason this does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

this one worked:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$variables) { 
  //view name as body class
  $variables['view_title'] = '';
  $route = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteObject();
  if ($route) {
    $view_title = $route->getDefault('_title');
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'view-' . Html::cleanCssIdentifier($view_title);
  }
}
```

Comment: What if the view title has an empty space? ex: `Hello World`

Comment: @NoSssweat, use the `Html::cleanCssIdentifier()` method. For example, `'view-' . Html::cleanCssIdentifier($view_title);`.

The method prepares a string to be used as a CSS identifier. It replaces spaces and everything.